# JSON mySQL merge

Tags: mysql, json, inner-join

столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Имею JSON массив в mySQL

```
[{"tags": "3A91DE97-11EE-4821-872E-F4CA8E3F24FB", 
  "phone": "88005553535", 
  "comment": "Какой-то коммент"}, 
 {"tags": "011C83E0-5BC9-46B3-8EC0-D57BE4DC33EF", 
  "phone": "84954445353", 
  "comment": "Какой-то коммент 2"}]
```

**tags** - GUID из другой таблицы

**phone** - номер телефона

**comment** - комментарий

Такой вопрос, как создать такое объединение, которое заменит мне tags на data из таблицы `tags` по GUID, который есть в этом поле

На данный момент сделал такой вариант:

```
    SELECT
    JSON_REPLACE(p.phones, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(p.phones,'one', t.guid,NULL,'$[*].tags')) ,t.data) AS phones
FROM
    phonebook p
        LEFT JOIN tags t ON
        JSON_SEARCH(
                p.phones,
                'one',
                t.guid,
                NULL,
                '$[*].tags'
            ) IS NOT NULL
```

Но по итогу получаю немного не то, что я бы хотел, он дублирует строки. 
Вот что я получаю в ответ

```
[{"tags": "3A91DE97-11EE-4821-872E-F4CA8E3F24FB", 
  "phone": "88005553535", 
  "comment": "Какой-то коммент 1"}, 
 {"tags": [{"text": "Текст тега от 011C83E0-5BC9-46B3-8EC0-D57BE4DC33E", 
            "color": "blue"}], 
  "phone": "84954445353", 
  "comment": "Какой-то коммент 2"}]
```

А хотелось бы получить

```
[{"tags": [{"text": "Текст тега от 3A91DE97-11EE-4821-872E-F4CA8E3F24FB", 
            "color": "blue"}], 
  "phone": "88005553535", 
  "comment": "Какой-то коммент 1"}, 
 {"tags": [{"text": "Текст тега от 011C83E0-5BC9-46B3-8EC0-D57BE4DC33E", 
            "color": "blue"}], 
  "phone": "84954445353", 
  "comment": "Какой-то коммент 2"}]
```

Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Comment: Replace обновляет одну запись только один раз - даже если она имеет несколько соответствий. Для решения задачи надо разобрать массив на элементы-объекты (JSON_TABLE), в каждом из элементов выполнить замену, а потом собрать обратно в массив.

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Попробую!